# some Android text lines appeared on the screen that are changing constantly

Tags: screen, samsung-galaxy-note

It's about a few days since some text lines (white and green) appeared on the display and I don't know what changes I have made unintentionally that caused the appearance of those lines.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @THelper: Would it help if I take a photo of it?

Comment: @Gigili A picture might help also, but if you don't know how to take a screenshot, look here:http://www.allaboutgalaxynote.com/3-fast-ways-to-create-screenshot-in-galaxy-note-without-using-any-apps/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **Settings**, go to *Developer options* and un-check the *Show CPU usage*:

[image]